# Syntax error: unexpected '->' in call for destroy method

Tags: php, laravel

In  my laravel app and index.blade.php and edit.blade.php won't show up becauses of my calls to the "destroy" and "update" methods.

Honestly no idea what to do. Looked at other examples and cant see any differences.

index.blade.php (the problematic line is the one with the form):

```php
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>This is your task list</h1>
<ul>
@foreach($tasks as $task)
<li>
    <a style ="padding-right:5%" href = "{{route('tasks.edit',$task->id)}}">{{$task->title}} </a>

    <form method = 'POST' action ="{{action('TaskController@destroy', @task->id)}}">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<div class = "form-group">
<input type = "submit" class= "form-control" name = "submit" value = "Delete">
</div>
</form>
</li>

@endforeach
</ul>
<a href = "{{route('tasks.create')}}">Add a new Todo </a>
@endsection
```

edit.blade.php (same here, problem lies in the form line):

```php
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Edit Existing Task</h1>
<form method = 'POST' action = "{{action('TaskController@update' , @task->id)}}">
@method('PATCH')
@csrf
<div class = "form-group">
<label for = "title">Task to edit:</label>
<input type = "text" class= "form-control" name = "title" value = "{{$task->title}}">
</div>

<div class = "form-group">
<input type = "submit" class= "form-control" name = "submit" value = "Save">
</div>
</form>
```

> syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\task\resources\views\tasks\index.blade.php)

Comment: `@task`? Maybe `$task`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of your blade files you have used `@task` instead of `$task` so Change this

```
<form method = 'POST' action = "{{action('TaskController@update' , @task->id)}}">
```

To

```
<form method = 'POST' action = "{{action('TaskController@update' , $task->id)}}">
```

Comment: Yep this is it.

Comment: Good catch :) Didn't even noticed that typo.

Comment: Yups. it happens sometime. I've also gone through same thing many times :p

Answer (score 0):

The variable being passed on the actions of both the `<form>` needs to be `$task->id` instead of `@task->id`.